# orbit-slider: caption problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, responsive-design

I am new to responsive design. I am trying to use Foundation orbit slider for my project.
I am not able get the captions displayed for the pictures. I have following code...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
    <div id="slider">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/pic3.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

  <span class="orbit-caption" id="captionOne">Here is a caption1...</span>
  <span class="orbit-caption" id="captionTwo">Here is a caption2...</span>
  <span class="orbit-caption" id="captionThree">Here is a caption3...</span>
</div>
```

When I tried this for first time it didn't work. I tried looking in Stackoverflow and tried
the fix given by commanderdemon. Still it didn't work. I dont even get the dark strip for caption on the pics.

In foundation.css I see that display is set to none for the class orbit-caption

```
/* Captions ---------------------- */
.orbit-caption { display:none; font-family: inherit; }

.orbit-wrapper .orbit-caption { background: black; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);  
    z-index: 30; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 7px 0; font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

By **removing** it I was able to see a tiny black strip (around 10px high) on the pic and the 3 captions are all appended and fallen out of the pictures.

Should the pictures be less than 400px in height? Is there a css fix required for this?
What am I doing wrong?

I have tried using just image tag instead of anchor tag. Both have same result.

P.S. I am using the foundation.css as it comes with download. I am not allowed to post a screen shot either...

**Sorry found the mistake... I was supposed to put data-caption="#captionOne"** 
-Jody

Comment: It'll be pretty tough to help you without a demo or at least your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your js are 'captions' set to 'true' ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
       $("#featured").orbit({
           captions : true
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide same ID in image tag as in SPAN caption tag